# Email without stylesheet using swiftmailer. Can template have external stylesheet?

Tags: css, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm setting swiftmailer body using renderView method.

```
->setBody( $this->renderView(confirm.html.twig
```

Template have external stylesheet and in browser looks good but delivered message is without style.
When tag is styled inside template, then delivered message have style.

Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is practically no support for external stylesheets when it comes to building emails. Your safest bet is to push all of your styles inline to make sure that it display correctly in all email clients.